# Efficient multiplication of a large number of matrix pairs

Tags: python, numpy

I have two sets of 10,000 matrices stored  as two `ndarrays` A and B:

```
A.shape = (10000, 2, 10)
B.shape = (10000, 10, 2)
```

What is an efficient way to multiply these matrices in order to get :

```
C.shape = (10000, 2, 2)
```

with `C[k,:,:] = dot(A[k,:,:], B[k,:,:])`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `numpy.einsum`:

```
np.einsum('ijk,ikl->ijl', A, B)
```